# Hide div on click (and stay hidden even when the page is refreshed)

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, show-hide

I am currently attempting to make a notification box that can be removed when clicking "X". The problem is that it re-appears every time the site is loaded. So when visiting another part of the page the div re-appears.

Is it possible for it to stay away until visitors next visit of website in any way? Or maybe not make it load again before X minutes?

Comment: You can use the localStorage within your javascript code to save and retrieve the notification box status

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know I just can't seem to find any information on the topic.

Comment: as mentioned by @FedericoScardina you can use `localStorage`, or another way will be `cookies`

Comment: Thanks @SamvelAleqsanyan. Trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PHP 5 Sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp). This is a start in the right direction.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if this worked for you.